# "You look tired!" In which countries is this a compliment?

Tags: international-travel, culture, cultural-awareness

In which countries/cultures is "You look tired" a compliment?

A travel for work and I often hear the phrase "You look tired" delivered as a compliment. The underlying message seems to be "You are working very hard".

In the US people might very well get mad at you (although they might not show it) if you tell them something like that.

Comment: In English? Or are you translating the phrase to English? Where have you heard it used?

Comment: In English from people who speak it as their second language.

Comment: `The underlying message seems to be "You are working very hard"` is this your assumption or you have asked about it?

Comment: I have asked about it in a couple of occasions and got similar answers. I wonder how common it is by country/culture. Or whether it's a "lost in translation" thing.

Comment: care to share where did you hear this?

Comment: In the US, if you know the person, saying "You look tired" in a sympathetic tone is an invitation to share whatever has been going on--car broke down, work is busy, etc.

Comment: As above, I would see it as a sympathetic comment rather than a compliment  And not the first thing to say to someone unless a friend or relative.

Comment: A woman's magazine (probably Cosmopolitan) once said that if a man says you look tired he means you look old. Best avoided I think.

Comment: I'd argue that in Europe this is usually not meant as a compliment but rather some form of sympathy. For example, if you receive a visitor who you know had a long journey, you may say: "You look tired. You probably want to get to get some rest now." Still, you should only say that if the person makes the impression.

Comment: So we all agree that US, Europe, and most likely the rest of the Western world don't react well to such comment. Can anyone speak for other countries or continents? How about Asia for instance?

Comment: On a related note, telling a British person that they look [*tired and emotional*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tired_and_emotional) would mean something quite different...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off topic as it's not about travel.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a survey, not a question, and it's asking about multiple countries, not about travel.

Comment: @DavidRicherby This is not a survey, it's a very specific question. Please also note that Travel and Culture go together and they are not independent topics. Finally, I strongly believe that the strict interpretation of StackExchange policies hurt the community more than they help it.

Comment: @Gevorg The fact that culture and travel are related doesn't mean that any question about culture is a question about travel (or vice-versa).

Answer (score 7):

In Japan it is a standard greeting, for example when you meet someone in the evening and have a drink, when you finished work for the day, when congratulating someone for having finished some project:

```
お疲れ様です　otsukaresama desu
```

which means something like "you are tired", but is better translated to something like "Good work!"/"You're working hard!"

This greeting is polite and can be used both to people close and not-so-close, as well as your superiors.

On a similar note, in Japan it is actually okay to sleep during meetings, to some extent. There is a specific phrase,

```
居眠り　inemuri
```

which literally means "present sleep", i.e., the person is sleeping but still present in the sense that if his name is called he will promptly wake up and reply to whatever question he is asked. This is a sign of working very hard, and is therefore not necessarily (depending on circumstances) seen as a bad thing.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Is this something common in Asia?

Comment: IMHO it's more a farewell than a greeting.  The canonical usage is when somebody is leaving the office at the end of the day: they say *Osaki ni shitsurei shimasu* (お先に失礼します, roughly "Sorry to leave before you") and everybody responds *Otsukaresama desu* (literally "You are tired", but meaning "Thank you, you've worked hard").  And AFAIK this is only used in Japan.

Comment: @jpatokai by "greeting" I simply meant as a general way of... what is the general word for greeting+farewells? Anyway, you are correct that it can be used for farewells, but is also used for greetings. Especially instead of "kanpai" when saying cheers during the first drink of the day.

Comment: @Gevorg having lived for the major part of my life in Japan, I know Japan, but I do not know much about other Asian countries.

Answer (score 0):

A Google search didn’t throw up anywhere where this is a compliment except for Nigeria https://www.quora.com/Is-it-rude-to-tell-people-they-look-tired

Comment: Maybe Google doesn't know everything after all! ;)

Comment: Or, possibly, it is correct in that it is not a complement anywhere *but* Nigeria. This question might get better answers at the English language stackexchange.

Comment: Everything is possible. I don't think that the "English language" site applies here though.

Comment: You clearly indicates this was English usage in comments on the original post. The ELU stack can help identify which regional variants of English have this "positive" connotation.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas they clearly indicated they've heard it in English *from people speaking it as a second language*. That absolutely isn't a reason to think it's common in any regional variety of English, or that ELU is the appropriate place to ask.

Comment: @ChrisH and then refused to indicate where the original speakers were from or their native languages, so we're left speculating with "English".

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas left speculating, sure. Quite why the result of that speculation would be "English" is the part I'm struggling with. And I hardly think it's fair to say they "refused" to indicate where the speakers are from - presumably OP would have no need to ask this question in the first place if they knew that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Americans would be any more sensitive to this than anyone else.

If you've been working hard and look it, it's more a sign of empathy than a compliment.  I wouldn't be offended by this in the least if I actually was tired.